# Is it possible to release a public and private version of an Android app?

Tags: android, release

I have a group of users that supported the app I am developing via Kickstarter, who have already pre-purchased the game. I'd like to offer those users the game for free and figured that releasing a free version of the game privately for them would be the best solution. The problem is that I read that you cannot release a private version of an app and a public version. I just wanted to know if there was a way around this. That is, is there a way to have an application be private and free to a select group of users while also having a public, paid version of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options here:

- Create two separate apps: (use flavors in Android Studio)

  - Free, private (beta channel only) app
  - Paid, public app
- Create one single app, with in-app billing to access full features. Your testers can get a refund or you can manage their privileges some other way.